# Bootstrap / Foundaion Column issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, zurb-foundation

I have a weird problem with bootstrap columns.

I am using grid as below:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3">Content1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">Content2</div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">Content3</div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">Content4</div>
</div>
```

And these columns are randomly generated and sometimes there can be no content in any of the columns like as below

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3">Content1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">Content3</div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">Content4</div>
</div>
```

> Now the problem is that when there is no content in column2 then column3 content shifts left. I want to avoid that.

Below is the presentation that i am getting

**When all blocks have content**

```
Content1    Content2    Content3    Content4
```

**When second block do not have content**

```
Content1    Content3                 Content4
```

Representation that want is that:

```
Content1                 Content3    Content4
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an inner Div inside your columns and set min-height property for better solution:

**New HTML**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="column-content">Content1</div></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="column-content"></div></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="column-content">Content3</div></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="column-content">Content4</div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.column-content {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Taken help form this page: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-reference/css-min-height-property.php

Comment: This is the best solution one should follow,,,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be to add “`&nbsp;`” to the end of a column.

It will not change much your lay out but will help with “empty” columns

Comment: Well, you already have something wrong with a general bootstrap use (So “code practices” lol) (or your custom CSS, or other). If you test your sample with original bootstrap and nothing else, it works as excepted. I was trying to find a quick solution to a problem.

Comment: please do not take it in offended way. It was a general comment for using &nbsp;

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/CWSCIPD72e not offended, just pointing out that you can spend a lot of hours tracking THAT css class that mess up with your display, or add &nbsp; :) choice is yours

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such a solution in bootstrap for your problem.
 But You can use an jquery script for checking the div is null or not, if null assign an css property **display:none;** to that div( using script)